# Rails Import CSV - No Route Matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, methods, import

I'm very new to Rails. I'm currently trying to import data from an csv file into my rails application. However, when I followed examples and guides online, I got the error: ***No route matches {:action=>"import_csv", :controller=>"lists"}*** I've already added it in my routes.rb though. Can anyone help me check what is wrong if my codes to cause to 'no route matches' error? Below are my files:

#### lists_controller.rb

```
def import_csv

require 'fastercsv' 

respond_to do |format|
@csv=params[:file].read
@n=0
@parsed_file = CSV.parse(csv)
@parsed_file.each  do |row|
  @user_new = User.new
  @user_new.first_name = row[0]
  @user_new.last_name = row[1]
  @user_new.email = row[2]
  @user_new.address = row[3]
  @user_new.city = row[4]
  @user_new.state = row[5]
  @user_new.zip = row[6]
  @user_new.country = row[7]
  @user_new.notes = row[8]
  @user_new.birthday = row[9]
  @user_new.home_number = row[10]
  @user_new.mobile_number = row[11]
  @user_new.list_id = list_id
  @user_new.save
  @n=@n+1
  GC.start if n%50==0
    flash[:notice] = "CSV Imported Successfully, with  #{n} records"                                
end

format.html { redirect_to lists_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
  end
```

#### app/views/lists/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(:list, :url => list_import_csv_path,  :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="dump_file">Select a CSV File :</label></td>
        <td ><%= file_field_tag :file %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'><%= submit_tag 'Submit' %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

#### routes.rb

```
  resources :lists do
    get 'import_csv'
    #match '/import_csv/:id' => 'lists#import_csv', :as => :import_csv
  end
```

#### rake routes

```
    identities GET    /identities(.:format)                        identities#index
                  POST   /identities(.:format)                        identities#create
     new_identity GET    /identities/new(.:format)                    identities#new
    edit_identity GET    /identities/:id/edit(.:format)               identities#edit
         identity GET    /identities/:id(.:format)                    identities#show
                  PUT    /identities/:id(.:format)                    identities#update
                  DELETE /identities/:id(.:format)                    identities#destroy
newsletter_cancel GET    /newsletters/:newsletter_id/cancel(.:format) newsletters#cancel
      newsletters GET    /newsletters(.:format)                       newsletters#index
                  POST   /newsletters(.:format)                       newsletters#create
   new_newsletter GET    /newsletters/new(.:format)                   newsletters#new
  edit_newsletter GET    /newsletters/:id/edit(.:format)              newsletters#edit
       newsletter GET    /newsletters/:id(.:format)                   newsletters#show
                  PUT    /newsletters/:id(.:format)                   newsletters#update
                  DELETE /newsletters/:id(.:format)                   newsletters#destroy
  list_import_csv GET    /lists/:list_id/import_csv(.:format)         lists#import_csv
            lists GET    /lists(.:format)                             lists#index
                  POST   /lists(.:format)                             lists#create
         new_list GET    /lists/new(.:format)                         lists#new
        edit_list GET    /lists/:id/edit(.:format)                    lists#edit
             list GET    /lists/:id(.:format)                         lists#show
                  PUT    /lists/:id(.:format)                         lists#update
                  DELETE /lists/:id(.:format)                         lists#destroy
            users GET    /users(.:format)                             users#index
                  POST   /users(.:format)                             users#create
         new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                         users#new
        edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                    users#edit
             user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                         users#show
                  PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                         users#update
                  DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                         users#destroy
```

Comment: run `rake routes` and paste the output. Edit: Nevermind, issue is in config/routes.rb

Comment: @PedroNascimento In my case I can't find the path to export.csv in rake routes, where should it be?

Comment: @TPR please ask a new question and link it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is submitted with a POST, while the route is for a GET. Either pass `:method => :get` to the `form_for` helper, or change your route to `post` (I would prefer the former though, since you're requesting data, not changing anything on the server).

To specify GET method for a form, you would do

```
<%= form_for (:list, :url => list_import_csv_path, :method => :get, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

I'm also not sure if it's a good idea to force start garbage collection - it'd kill your performance if it kicks in while processing requests. Leftover objects should get garbage collected automatically.

I'd also extract the User export part (probably into a static method on the `User model`):

```
require 'faster_csv'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.import_from_csv(file)
    CSV.parse(file).each do |row|
      u = User.new(:first_name => row[0], :last_name => row[1] ...etc)
      return false if !u.save
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in the controller:

```
def import_csv
  respond_to do |format|
    if !User.import_from_csv(params[:file])
      format.html { render :show, :error => "Some error here" }
      format.json { render :json => "Some error here", :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to lists_url, :notice => "Import successful!" }
      format.json { :head => :ok }
    end
  end  
end
```

Comment: oh okay! Is there any better way to do so? I'm very new to Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Use `post` instead of `get` in your `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: it still gives me the error: No route matches {:action=>"import_csv", :controller=>"lists"}